# Android - Mindfulness Data using Health Connect

Tags: android, types, sdk, healthconnect

I'm doing Mindfulness reading data using Health Connect SDK, but I can't find Mindfulness data like hours of mindful or something like that in the SDK.

In list of [Data types](https://developer.android.com/guide/health-and-fitness/health-connect/data-and-data-types/data-types) I saw in Activity type:
"Activity: This captures any activity that a user does. It can include health and fitness activities like running, swimming, meditation, and sleep."
It has meditation data type, I'm not sure meditation data is Mindfulness Data or not.

So I wonder where could I find and query Mindfulness data or is this data support in Health Connect?